# DynamoDB Filtering with 3 or more fields

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Say, I have a dynamodb with following schema:

```
{
    Field1: “”,
    Field2: “”,
    Field3: “”,
    Field4: “”,
    Field5: “”
}
```

Can I write a query in dynamo which will do filtering on 3 or more fields: field2, field3, field4 by creating indexes on some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this schema, No, but you can use composite sort key or Index as below

```
Primary key: Field1
Sort key: Field2#Field3#Field4
```

then if the result is not very large, using Scan operation for filter more fields.so its depend on your data structure. the composite sort key is good for hierarchical data scenario.